# git merge appear conflict,how to solve?

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

My project have a master and a branch named develop. I write some code in a java file named A in develop, than i  switch to the master . when I merge the develop branch, i get the latest code of develop branch  to master. Until now,no errors. But problems appear behind! i switch to branch name develop,when i continue write some code  in the file named A in develop.than I push the file to remote branch named develop. I switch to master, and merge the develop branch. appear conflict in the file named A! why ? and Please tell how to sole it .  if i merge the file conflict continue. There are  still conflicts in the file in next.! Please help me to solve it !

Comment: If you could include your code, this would help to understand the issue and assist you.

Comment: the file A my be  any one row code.  the problem is no relationship with java code.

Answer (score 0):

1. If there are multiple people working on this project, I'd recommend taking a pull from the remote branch before making any changes. This would help avoid the merge conflicts that may arise as other people might be making changes to the same file.
2. If you are the only one making a change in this project, I'd recommend taking a look at this document [Git Branching - Basic Branching and Merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) , especially under the **Basic Merge Conflicts** heading.

Comment: i seed ,but there is no scene for my problem, my problem is a master branch,and a develop branch, I update a file on develop branch, than switch to master and merge develop branch. but i do not delete the develop branch and i continue to code in the previous file that merged to master branch . so bad,when i switch to master branch ,i meet to the conflict in the file. if i merge the conflict in this time, But I will not delete the develop branch,if i update the old file ,the conflict will appear!